# Check if a user has a profile Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a Profile model that has a OneToOne relation with User model. How do I check if the signed in user already has a profile controller? And if no create one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (!$user->profile()->exists()) {
   Profile::create(['user_id' => $user->id]);
}
```

or

```
if (!auth()->user()->profile()->exists()) {
   Profile::create(['user_id' => $user->id]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In laravel you can check if relations exists or not

```
Auth::User()->has('profile')->exists();
```

Or

```
Auth::user()->profile()->exists();
```

Or

```
$profile = Auth::User()->profile()->first();
if (!$profile) // when doesn't exists
{
   // code goes here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to use `firstOrCreate` to handle it:

```
$profile = $user->profile()->firstOrCreate([], [
    'field' => 'value',
    ...
]);
```